# lodash _.partition method explained

Tags: javascript, lodash

I just discovered lodash.js and it's freaking GREAT man, however I stumbled onto an example which had me scratching my head.

```js
let numbers = [4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42];
let isEven = function(n) {
    return n % 2 === 0;
};

let [evens, odds] = _.partition(numbers, isEven);

// evens: [4, 8, 16, 42]
// odds: [15, 23]
```

According to the documentation partition creates ONE array which contains two arrays containing results which returned true or false respectively, then how the outcome of the function TWO arrays?

Comment: Change `let [evens, odds] =` to `let result =` or similar and compare.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the destructuring assignment allows you to assign the first element of the returned array to variable evens, and the second to odds. Since the returned array contains two arrays, both of the variables now refer to one-dimensional arrays.